# String parser that stores parsed strings in **arg[] does a segmentation fault

Tags: c

I have a school project where I have to code a shell in C and I'm stuck on the parser function. Would really appreciate some help in understanding where is my error and if my code is good at all. Thanks in advance !

```
#define BUFFSIZE 1024

char buf[BUFFSIZE];

int parse_line(char *s,char **newargv[]){
    char *sppos;
    int arraypos = 0;
    int offset;
    int newargc;
    *newargv = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*(1+100));

    do{
        if(strpbrk(s," ") != NULL){
            char *cpy = calloc(40,sizeof(char));
            sppos = strpbrk(s," "); //Locates position of space char in string
            offset = sppos-s;
            strncpy(cpy,s,offset); //copies string before space
            *(newargv)[arraypos] = cpy;
            arraypos++;
        }
        else{
            *(newargv)[arraypos] = s;
        }

    s=s+offset+1;   //moves pointer to position after space

    }while(strpbrk(s," ") != NULL);

    *(newargv)[arraypos] = NULL;

    newargc = arraypos+1;
    return newargc;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char *input;
    char **newargv;
    int newargc;
    while(1) {
    if (scanf("%s",input) == EOF) break;

    char *cwd = getcwd(buf,BUFFSIZE);
    *(cwd+100) = '\0';
    newargc = parse_line(input,&newargv);
    printf("%s",cwd);

    }   
    return 0;
}
```

**UPEC L2 INFO - TP Shell**

Comment: `strncpy()` doesn't add a null terminator.

Comment: BTW, if you're just searching for a single character, use `strchr()`. It also looks like you're implementing your own version of `strtok()`, why don't you use that?

Comment: Lots of problems here. Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  , as it is not possible to verify correct use of `args` without seeing how you set up the argument and how you use it afterwards

Comment: calling `free` on a memory block that you're trying to return, is probably a mistake

Comment: Don't copy the string into a different location (especially one that you subsequently free).  Just assign argv[i] to point to the correct location in s (and set null terminators appropriately)

Comment: eg (assuming all the runs of whitespace are exactly one long) `*sppos = '\0'; *args[arraypos] = sppos + 1;`

Comment: @Barmar strtok has various problems, such as non-reentrancy and modifying the source

Comment: In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714), `sizeof(char)` is always `1` and is superfluous.

Comment: @M.M The second problem can be resolve by making a copy of the source. Since he's making a copy of each token in this code, it's effectively the same.

Comment: If re-entrancy is required, use `strtok_r()`. But that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: The function ```parse_line()``` will be used in a loop that asks for user to input for commands to parse the commands and print them afterwards

Comment: The segmentation fault is almost certainly due to not adding null terminators to the tokens.

Comment: @Barmar What are tokens ?

Comment: @Barmar "almost certainly" ? freeing memory still in use seems to be a  likely culprit, especially if we consider  malloc'd space is likely to come zeroed on modern OSs; and also I suspect writing out of bounds of the `argv`

Comment: @HowLong The words you're splitting the line into are tokens.

Answer (score 1):

The segmentation fault is probably from not initializing argv.
An example of the call might help.

And the type might be wrong too.  The current type is an array of pointers to pointers to char.  You probably wanted a pointer to an array of pointers to char.  Or maybe pointer to pointer to pointer to char.

```
char *(*argv)[]
char ***argv
```

In the current usage, you must make an array, and then a collection of pointers to char, which the array values must be initialized to point to.  Then parse_line() gets called.

With the revised definition, parse_line should determine how many entries it is returned, and allocate an array of pointers of that count plus one.  Then assign this to `*argv`.  Then the string assignments are are `(*argv)[arraypos] = whatever;`

Also, another failure will occur because you `free(cpy);` after returning `cpy` in the argv array.  This will only happen after you return from parse_line(), and won't normally be a segmentation fault, at least not at once.

Finally, I agree with not using strtok.  Once you start adding additional parsing rules (like quoting), it becomes non-viable.

Comment: I have added the main function, is the argv as one of the `main()`'s argument initialised or should I malloc a space for it ?

Comment: "The segmentation fault is probably from not initializing argv." argv is pretty certainly the one from main(), however there's no guarantees about the size of the buffer used for it.

Comment: @HowLong  With that main(): 
code.c: In function 'main':
code.c:46:5: warning: passing argument 2 of 'parse_line' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
code.c:6:5: note: expected 'char ***' but argument is of type 'char **'

Comment: @HowLong  You should NOT be trying to change main()'s argv.  You should be building another one with your data.  Declare: `char **newargv;`   Pass as:  `&newargv`   In parse_line, first do:  `*newargv = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*(1+count_of_args));`  Then you can start filling in the strings: `(*newargv)[index] = value;`

Comment: @DavidG. Followed your guidance and it seem to work, it segfaults only when too long strings are added now. But I'm having problems to access the elements of the argv array , I tried a `for( int x = 0;x<=(newargc - 1);x++){ printf("%s",*newargv[x]);} `and this gives a segfault. would it be because each cell of the array isn't terminated by a `NULL` character ?

Comment: @HowLong  Possible, but probably not.  If it is `char **newargv;` then you print `newargv[x]`, not `*newargv[x]`.  Advice: get a C compiler that includes type checking!  The lack of NUL termination will bite you as well.  The long string failure is probably the use of scanf --- use fgets instead.  One more suggestion: get a good debugger, like gdb.  This can show you where the exception occurred.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code after correction and it seems to work.
Still need to check if the strings are well parsed inside the array and make the program terminate properly when CTRL+D(EOF) is pressed.
Thanks for all the help

```
int parse_line(char *s,char **newargv[]){
    char *sppos;
    int arraypos = 0;
    int offset;
    int newargc;
    *newargv = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*(1+BUFFSIZE));

    do{
        if(strpbrk(s," ") != NULL){
            char *cpy = calloc(100,sizeof(char));
            sppos = strpbrk(s," "); //Locates position of space char in string
            offset = sppos-s;
            strncpy(cpy,s,offset); //copies string before space
            *(newargv)[arraypos] = cpy;
            arraypos++;
        }
        else{
            *(newargv)[arraypos] = s;
        }

    s=s+offset+1;   //moves pointer to position after space

    }while(strpbrk(s," ") != NULL);

    *(newargv)[arraypos] = NULL;

    newargc = arraypos+1;
    return newargc;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char input[BUFFSIZE];
    char **newargv;
    int newargc;


    while(1) {
    if (read(1,input,BUFFSIZE) == EOF) break;

    char *dir;

    dir = getcwd ((char *) NULL, BUFFSIZE);

    if (dir == NULL) perror ("getcwd");
    else
    {
        write(1,dir,BUFFSIZE);
        free (dir);
    }
    printf("$ ");
    newargc = parse_line(input,&newargv);

    printf("%s",input);


    }   
    return 0;
}
```